# biopython script giving error 'invalid syntax'

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to apply a biopython code for splitting a large fasta file. The code is the above one:

```
def batch_iterator():
    entry=True # to make sure the loop run once
    while entry:
        batch=[]
        while len(batch) < batch_size:
            try:
                entry=iterator.next()
            except StopIteration:
                entry=None
            if entry is None:
                #end of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch:
            yield batch
record_iter=SeqIO.parse(open('/home/to/file/sorted_sequence.fa', 'fasta')
for i, batch in enumerate (batch_iterator(record_iter, 93)):
    filename='gene_%i.fasta' % (i + 1)
    with open('/home/path/files/', filename, 'w') as ouput_handle:
        count=SeqIO.write(batch, ouput_handle, 'fasta')
    print ('Wrote %i records to %s' % (count, filename))
```

In the this line:
**for i, batch in enumerate (batch_iterator(record_iter, 93)):** is giving me 
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax** . But I cannot see the error, can anyone help me to find it, please?
I took the code from this http://biopython.org/wiki/Split_large_file
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis in this line

```
record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open('/home/to/file/sorted_sequence.fa', 'fasta')
```

try adding one

```
record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open('/home/to/file/sorted_sequence.fa'), 'fasta')
```

Comment: Yeap, I had a missing parenthesis but the right place is after the file name: `record_iter=SeqIO.parse(open('home/to/file/sorted_sequences.fa'), 'fasta')`